# How do I programmatically alter and rewrite the current path?

Tags: 8, uri

I have a multilingual site with 2 languages (English and French) and 4 ISO codes (us, gb, fr, and be). I want Drupal to understand that /us and /gb are aliases for /en. (They share the same content.)

Is there a way to programmatically achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I wanted using the following service.

#### services.yml

```yaml
mymodule.path_processor:
  class: Drupal\mymodule\PathProcessor\PathProcessor
  arguments: ['@language_manager', '@config.factory', '@path.alias_manager']
  tags:
    - { name: path_processor_inbound, priority: 200 }
```

#### PathProcessor.php

```php
/**
 * Processes the inbound path using path alias lookups.
 */
class PathProcessorCustom implements InboundPathProcessorInterface, OutboundPathProcessorInterface {

  protected $language_manager;
  protected $configFactory;
  protected $aliasManager;

  public function __construct(LanguageManagerInterface $language_manager, ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory, AliasManagerInterface $alias_manager) {
    $this->languageManager = $language_manager;
    $this->configFactory = $config_factory;
    $this->aliasManager = $alias_manager;
  }

  public function processInbound($path, Request $request) {
    if (!strpos($path, '/admin/')) {
      $path = $this->removeISOCode($path);
    }

    return $path;
  }

  public function processOutbound($path, &$options = array(), Request $request = NULL, BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata = NULL) {
    if (!strpos($path, '/admin/')) {
      $path = $this->insertISOCode($path);
    }

    return $path;
  }

  protected function removeISOCode($path) {
    $langcode = $this->languageManager
      ->getDefaultLanguage()
      ->getId();
    $isocodes = $this->getISOCodeMapping();
    $path_items = explode('/', $path);
    if (isset($path_items[1]) && strlen($path_items[1]) == 2 && in_array($path_items[1], $isocodes[$langcode])) {
      $config_negotiation_url = $this->configFactory->get('language.negotiation')->get('url');
      if (!in_array($path_items[1], $config_negotiation_url['prefixes'])) {
        array_splice($path_items, 1, 1);
        if (count($path_items) == 1) {
          $config_system_site = $this->configFactory->get('system.site')->get('page');
          $path = $config_system_site['front'];
        }
        else {
          $path = implode('/', $path_items);
          $path = $this->aliasManager->getPathByAlias($path, 'en');
        }
      }
    }

    return $path;
  }

  protected function insertISOCode($path) {
    $path_items = explode('/', $path);
    if (isset($path_items[1]) && strlen($path_items[1]) == 2 && $path_items[1] == 'gb') {
      $config_negotiation_url = $this->configFactory->get('language.negotiation')->get('url');
      if (!in_array($path_items[1], $config_negotiation_url['prefixes'])) {
        $path_items[1] = $language;
      }
    }

    return implode('/', $path_items);
  }
    
  protected function getISOCodeMapping() {
    return [
      'en' => ['gb', 'us'],
      'fr' => ['fr', 'be']
    ];
  }

}
```

What I do is decompose the URL, remove what I know I don't need, and map the URL to an actual content URL.