# Change the URL of a node based on parent path

Tags: 8, nodes, routes

So let's say I have a basic page node.

I want to have this as an entity reference inside another content type - let's say an event content type.

So let's say that the event content has a url like `baseurl.com/eventblahblahblah`

When a user clicks over to the basic page that is the reference on node `eventblahblahblah`, I want them to go to `baseurl.com/eventblahblahblah/basicpagenodehere` - this needs to be the URL in the browser.

In addition, `basicpagenodehere` can be in multiple references - so if `basicpagenodehere` is also referenced by `event2blah`, then I want it to also be located at the url `baseurl.com/event2blah/basicpagenodehere`

I'm looking at possibly doing this with alterRoute -

```
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
  }
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is the correct place to do it.

This link suggests maybe PathProcessor, but I don't think that would change the actual URL on the node at the end of processing:

[How to alter and rewritte current path programmatically in Drupal 8?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/213855/how-to-alter-and-rewritte-current-path-programmatically-in-drupal-8)

**So how do I set a dynamic URL based on referring node?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The routing system is probably not the right place for this, you would need to rebuild the routing table whenever the content is changed, which is very slow.

PathProcessor is the right tool. By the way, path aliases are also implemented in a PathProcessor, the aliases are coming from a lookup table. You can change the path in and outbound dynamically or with your own lookup table if you need it for performance reasons.

Better for SEO would be a redirect to avoid duplicate content, but this changes the url in the browser, what you don't want.

---

Example for the symmetrical inbound/outbound (asked in the comments):

```
  public function processInbound($path, Request $request) {
    if (strpos($path, '/foo/') === 0) {
      $path = preg_replace('#^/foo#', '', $path);
    }
    return $path;
  }

  public function processOutbound($path, &$options = array(), Request $request = NULL, BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata = NULL) {
    $path = '/foo' . $path;
    return $path;
  }
```

This will add `/foo` to all paths.

**One way to approach this** could be, you get the child node `node/x` in the outbound processor as input, the parent node id from the current route. Then you get the title from each of both nodes and put the path together.

For inbound I suggest a third fix path parameter, so that you can identify this kind of path right away and scrap all but the title from the child node, query the node id and you are back where you started at `/node/x`.

Comment: When I change the outbound, I keep getting "path not found" - even when I change the inbound to the same thing. Am I misunderstanding what I am doing here? The outbound definitely changes the URL, but does not seem to correctly path to the node.

Comment: Yes, you have to do this symmetrically, inbound and outbound. But you can test this independ from each other. You can start with inbound by testing the url `baseurl.com/eventblahblahblah/basicpagenodehere` in the browser and debug how this gets changed inbound to the canonical url from the node.

Comment: Hrm, when I try symmetrically, I get "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." along with this: a:6:{s:5:"%type";s:61:"Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException";s:8:"@message";s:58:"None of the routers in the chain matched url - I think we're on the right track but it seems like a custom router might be necessary too?

Comment: All I've changed in ::processOutbound & ::processInbound is that I added "/foo" to the path when returned for testing purposes.

Comment: You don't need a custom route, internally you use the existing entity routes. Symmetrical means if you add it outbound you remove it inbound.

Comment: Oh got it. I thought that symmetrical meant that if you add it outbound you add it inbound too. I'll test adding it outbound and removing it inbound.

Comment: I'm just not getting how this is supposed to work practically. Can you add an example so I can see what you're talking about?

Comment: I've added an example for /foo.

Comment: This adds a foo inside the link (example: /foo/ait), however when I then click the link it does NOT send me to the node in question.

Comment: It does appear to work for admin paths.

Comment: Looking at the inbound paths, it is changing the inbound path to the correct one, but going to a node not found page. So I think we're 90% of the way there for this answer. Just need to figure out why it isn't working for nodes.

Comment: only reason why outbound shouldn't work is that you've hardcoded the links (and always clear the cache)

Comment: Links are definitely not hardcoded. URL Path settings are set on the nodes in question. And yes, I've cleared cache several times.

Comment: I've tested the code, all links including menus are getting a /foo before the path, `/node/1` gets `/foo/node/1`, `/alias-that-points-to-a-node` gets `/foo/alias-that-points-to-a-node` and all work when i click on them

Comment: but if you use aliases you have to set a priority higher than 100 for inbound, because the aliases only work if /foo has been removed before

Comment: I'm guessing it's the priority then, as, for example, /foo/node/117 works, but the alias /foo/ait does not. So I'll check that and report back.

Comment: Yep, when I set the priority higher, it worked fine with aliases. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Actually, I realized that while this allows me to add or remove an arbitrary string, how would I pass the parent pathing information in? I.e. the immediate previous page?

Comment: I've put an possible approach in the answer. This is probably not exactly what you have in mind, but I think you get the idea. Of course such  a solution needs some more thoughts and a lot of debugging.