# How do I create an alias for the node edit page?

Tags: 8, path-aliases

Pathauto can create path aliases for the node page. For example, it can change node/[nid] to project/[nid], where *project* is the  content type. It doesn't change the path for the node edit page, which is still node/[nid]/edit, instead of project/[nid]/edit as I would expect it to be.

How could I set the path alias to project/[nid]/edit for the node edit page in Drupal 8, when the content type is project?

Comment: Can you describe why you want to change node edit url? because all CRUD operation have some specific route provided by their module. You don't need to alter them.

Comment: Simple answer: you can't (with a module or config, this would require custom coding)

Comment: @Hudri – So, actually you can. The question is how.

Comment: Take a look at this [tutorial](https://thinkshout.com/blog/2016/07/drupal-8-routing-tricks-for-better-admin-urls/). This adds an alternative path to edit routes, but it does not replace the existing ones

Comment: Thanks! The tutorial works! Yes, this adds an alternative path to edit routes, but it does not replace the existing ones.

Comment: This is not possible by routing. You need an outbound path processor to make links content type aware, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/259326/global-preprocess-for-all-links, in your case inbound too, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/213855/how-to-alter-and-rewritte-current-path-programmatically-in-drupal-8 and finally [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) now merged into [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect).

Answer (score 2):

There is a module for that: [Sub-Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto)

From the module page:

> The Drupal Path module matches only full URLs when creating SEO-friendly aliases. This module extends that behavior by also matching known sub-paths and replacing them with their respective alias. For example, if user/1 is aliased to users/admin, this module rewrites the link to the user contact page user/1/contact to use the aliased URL users/admin/contact instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php` file in your module.

```
namespace Drupal\example\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 */
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($route = $collection->get('entity.node.edit_form')) {
      $route->setPath('/project/{node}/edit');
    }
  }

}
```

Use a `example.services.yml` file in your module (if the module is named example).

```
services:
  example.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\example\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones

Comment: Yes, the proposal works! But it applies to all content types and nodes. Suppose there are two content types: project and investor, could I achieve both 'project/nid/edit' and 'investor/nid/edit' ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I spent my morning attempting to figure out how to set the edit path differently for each individual content type. Unfortunately I came up short and compromised on using a single path that all of my content types would use (e.g. "/my_posts/edit/{node}". I'd love to know if anyone else out there knows how to do this.

Comment: What described by @4k4 in [his comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/273938/how-to-create-url-alias-for-node-edit-page#comment338034_273938) is the way I would go for it.