# How do I add a custom URL for node/add/{custom-content-type}?

Tags: 8, routes

I have a custom content type which I fill up with the help of the [Forms Steps](https://www.drupal.org/project/forms_steps) module.

I want to set custom URL for node/add/{custom-content-type}. I tried using a route subscriber and the following code.

```php
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) { 
  if ($route = $collection->get('node.add_page')) {
    $current_uri = \Drupal::request()->getRequestUri();
    if ($current_uri == "node/add/custom-content-type") {
      $route->setPath('/Custom-content/add');
    }
  }
}
```

The above code is not changing the URL. I am finding difficult to change the URL only for the custom content type.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: This can be done, but it would be easier to enable the path module and redirect module, and create an alias and a redirect to that alias.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create URL alias for node edit page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/273938/how-to-create-url-alias-for-node-edit-page)

Comment: Is there any good reason to change from node/add/[content-type] to [content-type]/add for a single content type? The reason why Drupal uses node/add/[content-type] is to avoid conflicts with other routes defined from third-party modules. Also, a placeholder cannot be the first part in the route path; the first part of a route path can only be a static string, like `'node'`.

Comment: The question doesn't make clear if there is any need to programmatically do what the question describes. I still think it's a bad idea, but if I were to do it, I would do it as @Jaypan described.